# How can I recover my menuStrip and statusStrip

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I don't know what happened but my menuStrip and statusStrip have disappeared! I'm using C# in Visual Studio 2010.

The only thing I was doing that may have caused this was trying to make the application icon show up in the task bar properly.  The form icons were fine but the application icon was randomly choosing windows icons.  I tried to put the icon into Resources instead of reading it from a file. Later, I tried to save the project but got an error (don't remember exactly what it said) related to not knowing where to get the icon.  I copied the icon into the Visual Studio/Projects/this program/Resources.  The save worked but then I noticed that my menuStrip and statusStrip were gone!

If no one knows how to recover them, maybe someone knows how to revert back to a previous version of the program.

Any help would be appreciated.

Program before
[image]

Program after
[image]

Comment: Is this how it looks when executed, or how it looks in Visual Studio designer mode?

Comment: This is the executed view. When it starts the cursor goes to the textbox labeled "OD" as you see in the pictures.

Comment: Good point. I missed that. Anyway, all I can think of is to manually go through `YourForm.Designer.cs` and look there, and in `YourForm.resx` (You can also right-click and open it with XML editor). Good luck!

Comment: Thanks ispiro, I forgot to mention that they disappeared in the designer mode too. I'll head over to the .cs and see if anything is there.  Do you know how to open the previous version of the program if all else fails?

Comment: In order to have me notified of your reply to me - you have to use `@ispiro`. About your question - No. I don't know how any old version can be retrieved. (Unless you're using some other software that will do that for you.) You said `they disappeared in the designer mode too` - I didn't mean check the designer **mode**. I meant open the C# file called `YourForm.Designer.cs` - I've seen traces there of things that don't appear in the designer mode itself. Such as Controls that are created but the code to add them to the Form's `Controls` is missing, so adding that "resurrects" them.

Comment: Sorry @ispiro, I usually remember to use the @. I understood you about YourForm.Designer.cs and started looking in there trying to find a clue. Don't see anything yet but got disconnected from my remote connection. Anyway thanks for the suggestions.